# Enclose lines in markers using regex in Gvim

Tags: regex, vim

I have following simple text:

```
one
a line
more lines
more text
end
```

I want to enclose each line in >> and << using regex. Following work individually:

```
:%s/^/>>/g
:%s/$/<</g
```

However, how can I do it with one command. I tried following but they do not work:

```
:%s/^([.]+)$/>>\1<</g
:%s/\v^([.]+)$/>>\1<</g
:%s/([.]+)/>>\1<</g
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use a macro to apply that on each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
:%s/^\(.*\)$/>>\1<</g
```

I notice a problem with your current attempts, for example this one:

```
:%s/^([.]+)$/>>\1<</g
```

You are matching a literal dot when you use `[.]`, which is a character class.  Doubtless, most of the time this pattern won't match any line, unless it consists entirely of dots.

Also, parentheses need to be escaped in Vim regexes.

Read [this excellent SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218789/adding-characters-at-the-start-and-end-of-each-line-in-a-file) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

```
:%s/.*/>>&<</
```

`&` mean `matched whole part`. And not require `g` flag.